# When I get home

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> When I get home, my dog **sits** at the gate waiting for me.

I think the above sentence expresses a habitual action, but would it be more correct to say

> When I get home, my dog will **be sitting** at the gate waiting for me.

Though this is also grammatically correct but this does not express a habitual action.
 
Am I correct with this analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. The first tells us how things are every day. The second makes a prediction about how things will be next time you arrive home.

They are both possible, but mean different things.

Comment: but I don't get why both the options are provided in the question and they ask me to choose the correct one

Comment: Nor do I.  I'm not answering a question about a test, but about the used of phrases in English.